# Can't seem to find the error in Mysql procedure Error 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
        DELIMITER $

        CREATE PROCEDURE geographical(IN appl_name1 varchar(500),
        IN appl_name2 varchar(500),
        IN appl_name3 varchar(500),
        IN appl_name4 varchar(500),
        IN granted char(1),
        IN oppose tinyint(4),
        IN beginDate date,
        IN endDate date,
        IN ipc varchar(300))
        BEGIN

            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS first_ctry;
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS second_ctry;
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS third_ctry;
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fourth_ctry;
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ref_ctry;


            SET @d1 = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS first_ctry AS 
            (SELECT a.docdb_family_id, a.appln_auth, MIN(a.appln_filing_date) as first_date 
            FROM patents_prod1.tls201_appln a
            INNER JOIN patents_prod1.tls207_pers_appln b ON b.appln_id = a.appln_id 
            INNER JOIN entity.combined c ON c.person_id = b.person_id
            INNER JOIN patents_prod1.tls209_appln_ipc d ON d.appln_id = a.appln_id
            WHERE c.name_friendly LIKE ', CONCAT('"', appl_name1, '"'),
            ' AND IF(',CONCAT('"',granted,'"'),' IS NOT NULL,a.granted LIKE ',CONCAT('"',granted,'"'),',1=1)
            AND IF(',CONCAT('"',oppose,'"'),' IS NOT NULL,a.isOpposed = ',CONCAT('"',oppose,'"'),',1=1)
            AND IF(',CONCAT('"',beginDate,'"'),' IS NOT NULL AND ',CONCAT('"',endDate,'"'),' IS NOT NULL,a.appln_filing_date BETWEEN ',CONCAT('"',beginDate,'"'),' and ',CONCAT('"',endDate,'"'),',1=1)
            AND IF(',CONCAT('"',beginDate,'"'),' IS NOT NULL AND ',CONCAT('"',endDate,'"'),' IS NULL,a.appln_filing_date BETWEEN ',CONCAT('"',beginDate,'"'),' and CURDATE(),1=1)
            AND IF(',CONCAT('"',ipc,'"'),' IS NOT NULL,FIND_IN_SET(d.ipc_class_symbol, ',CONCAT('"',ipc,'"'),'),1=1)
            AND a.appln_filing_year < 9999
            GROUP BY a.docdb_family_id, a.appln_auth
            ORDER BY a.docdb_family_id, first_date)');

            PREPARE stmtd1 FROM @d1;
            EXECUTE stmtd1;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmtd1;

            SET @s1 = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ref_ctry AS 
            (SELECT appln_auth, COUNT(distinct docdb_family_id) as ',CONCAT('"', appl_name1, '"'),' FROM first_ctry
            GROUP BY appln_auth
            ORDER BY ', CONCAT('"', appl_name1, '"'), ' DESC LIMIT 15)');

            PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s1;



            EXECUTE stmt1;

            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

            IF (appl_name2 IS NOT NULL OR appl_name2 <> '') THEN

                SET @d2 = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS second_ctry AS 
                (SELECT a.docdb_family_id, a.appln_auth, MIN(a.appln_filing_date) as first_date 
                FROM patents_prod1.tls201_appln a
                INNER JOIN patents_prod1.tls207_pers_appln b ON b.appln_id = a.appln_id 
                INNER JOIN entity.combined c ON c.person_id = b.person_id
                INNER JOIN patents_prod1.tls209_appln_ipc d ON d.appln_id = a.appln_id
                WHERE c.name_friendly LIKE ', CONCAT('"', appl_name2, '"'),
                ' AND IF(',CONCAT('"',granted,'"'),' IS NOT NULL,a.granted LIKE ',CONCAT('"',granted,'"'),',1=1)
                AND IF(',CONCAT('"',oppose,'"'),' IS NOT NULL,a.isOpposed = ',CONCAT('"',oppose,'"'),',1=1)
                AND IF(',CONCAT('"',beginDate,'"'),' IS NOT NULL AND ',CONCAT('"',endDate,'"'),' IS NOT NULL,a.appln_filing_date BETWEEN ',CONCAT('"',beginDate,'"'),' and ',CONCAT('"',endDate,'"'),',1=1)
                AND IF(',CONCAT('"',beginDate,'"'),' IS NOT NULL AND ',CONCAT('"',endDate,'"'),' IS NULL,a.appln_filing_date BETWEEN ',CONCAT('"',beginDate,'"'),' and CURDATE(),1=1)
                AND IF(',CONCAT('"',ipc,'"'),' IS NOT NULL,FIND_IN_SET(d.ipc_class_symbol, ',CONCAT('"',ipc,'"'),'),1=1)
                AND a.appln_filing_year < 9999
                GROUP BY a.docdb_family_id, a.appln_auth
                ORDER BY a.docdb_family_id, first_date)');

                PREPARE stmtd2 FROM @d2;
                EXECUTE stmtd2;
                DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmtd2;

                SET @s2 = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ref_ctry 
                ADD COLUMN ', CONCAT('"', appl_name2, '"'), ' int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0');

                PREPARE stmt2 FROM @s2;



                EXECUTE stmt2;

                DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;


                SET @s3 = CONCAT('UPDATE ref_ctry a
                SET ',CONCAT('"', appl_name2, '"'),' = (SELECT COUNT(distinct b.docdb_family_id) FROM second_ctry b WHERE b.appln_auth = a.appln_auth)');

                PREPARE stmt3 FROM @s3;



                EXECUTE stmt3;

                DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;

                IF (appl_name3 IS NOT NULL OR appl_name3 <> '') THEN

                        -- ADD THIRD COUNTRY DATA

                    SET @d3 = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS third_ctry AS 
                    (SELECT a.docdb_family_id, a.appln_auth, MIN(a.appln_filing_date) as first_date 
                    FROM patents_prod1.tls201_appln a
                    INNER JOIN patents_prod1.tls207_pers_appln b ON b.appln_id = a.appln_id 
                    INNER JOIN entity.combined c ON c.person_id = b.person_id
                    INNER JOIN patents_prod1.tls209_appln_ipc d ON d.appln_id = a.appln_id
                    WHERE c.name_friendly LIKE ', CONCAT('"', appl_name3, '"'),
                    ' AND IF(',CONCAT('"',granted,'"'),' IS NOT NULL,a.granted LIKE ',CONCAT('"',granted,'"'),',1=1)
                    AND IF(',CONCAT('"',oppose,'"'),' IS NOT NULL,a.isOpposed = ',CONCAT('"',oppose,'"'),',1=1)
                    AND IF(',CONCAT('"',beginDate,'"'),' IS NOT NULL AND ',CONCAT('"',endDate,'"'),' IS NOT NULL,a.appln_filing_date BETWEEN ',CONCAT('"',beginDate,'"'),' and ',CONCAT('"',endDate,'"'),',1=1)
                    AND IF(',CONCAT('"',beginDate,'"'),' IS NOT NULL AND ',CONCAT('"',endDate,'"'),' IS NULL,a.appln_filing_date BETWEEN ',CONCAT('"',beginDate,'"'),' and CURDATE(),1=1)
                    AND IF(',CONCAT('"',ipc,'"'),' IS NOT NULL,FIND_IN_SET(d.ipc_class_symbol, ',CONCAT('"',ipc,'"'),'),1=1)
                    AND a.appln_filing_year < 9999
                    GROUP BY a.docdb_family_id, a.appln_auth
                    ORDER BY a.docdb_family_id, first_date)');

                    PREPARE stmtd3 FROM @d3;
                    EXECUTE stmtd3;
                    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmtd3;


                    SET @s4 = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ref_ctry 
                    ADD COLUMN ', CONCAT('"', appl_name3, '"'), ' int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0');

                    PREPARE stmt4 FROM @s4;



                    EXECUTE stmt4;

                    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt4;


                    SET @s5 = CONCAT('UPDATE ref_ctry a
                    SET ',CONCAT('"', appl_name3, '"'),' = (SELECT COUNT(distinct b.docdb_family_id) FROM third_ctry b WHERE b.appln_auth = a.appln_auth)');

                    PREPARE stmt5 FROM @s5;



                    EXECUTE stmt5;

                    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt5;

                    IF (appl_name4 IS NOT NULL OR appl_name4 <> '') THEN

                        -- ADD FOURTH COUNTRY DATA
                        SET @d4 = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fourth_ctry AS 
                        (SELECT a.docdb_family_id, a.appln_auth, MIN(a.appln_filing_date) as first_date 
                        FROM patents_prod1.tls201_appln a
                        INNER JOIN patents_prod1.tls207_pers_appln b ON b.appln_id = a.appln_id 
                        INNER JOIN entity.combined c ON c.person_id = b.person_id
                        INNER JOIN patents_prod1.tls209_appln_ipc d ON d.appln_id = a.appln_id
                        WHERE c.name_friendly LIKE ', CONCAT('"', appl_name4, '"'),
                        ' AND IF(',CONCAT('"',granted,'"'),' IS NOT NULL,a.granted LIKE ',CONCAT('"',granted,'"'),',1=1)
                        AND IF(',CONCAT('"',oppose,'"'),' IS NOT NULL,a.isOpposed = ',CONCAT('"',oppose,'"'),',1=1)
                        AND IF(',CONCAT('"',beginDate,'"'),' IS NOT NULL AND ',CONCAT('"',endDate,'"'),' IS NOT NULL,a.appln_filing_date BETWEEN ',CONCAT('"',beginDate,'"'),' and ',CONCAT('"',endDate,'"'),',1=1)
                        AND IF(',CONCAT('"',beginDate,'"'),' IS NOT NULL AND ',CONCAT('"',endDate,'"'),' IS NULL,a.appln_filing_date BETWEEN ',CONCAT('"',beginDate,'"'),' and CURDATE(),1=1)
                        AND IF(',CONCAT('"',ipc,'"'),' IS NOT NULL,FIND_IN_SET(d.ipc_class_symbol, ',CONCAT('"',ipc,'"'),'),1=1)
                        AND a.appln_filing_year < 9999
                        GROUP BY a.docdb_family_id, a.appln_auth
                        ORDER BY a.docdb_family_id, first_date)');

                        PREPARE stmtd4 FROM @d4;
                        EXECUTE stmtd4;
                        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmtd4;



                        SET @s6 = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ref_ctry 
                        ADD COLUMN ', CONCAT('"', appl_name4, '"'), ' int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0');

                        PREPARE stmt6 FROM @s6;



                        EXECUTE stmt6;

                        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt6;


                        SET @s7 = CONCAT('UPDATE ref_ctry a
                        SET ',CONCAT('"', appl_name4, '"'),' = (SELECT COUNT(distinct b.docdb_family_id) FROM fourth_ctry b WHERE b.appln_auth = a.appln_auth)');

                        PREPARE stmt7 FROM @s7;



                        EXECUTE stmt7;

                        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt7;
                        -- FINAL TABLE FOR HORIZONTAL BAR CHARTS**
                        SELECT * FROM ref_ctry;

                    ELSE
                        SELECT * FROM ref_ctry;
                    END IF;


                ELSE
                    SELECT * FROM ref_ctry;
                END IF;


            ELSE 
                SELECT * FROM ref_ctry;
            END IF;



        END$

        DELIMITER ;
```

I am creating this procedure geographical.
When I am running it is giving me error

`call geographical("VESTAS",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);`
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

I have also written another procedure where there is no statement in quotes it is giving me an empty set.

Comment: You have a problem with null values.

Answer (score 0):

You are concating null to a string, this will result in null.
for example there is CONCAT('"', appl_name2, '"'), which appl_name2 is null, this will result in null instead of "null" (string).

You can try this to understand better :

```
select concat('first',null,'second');
```

I suggest you use COALESCE function, for example :

```
select concat('first',coalesce(appl_name2,'NULL','notnull'),'second');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for you to use prepared statements in your stored procedure. It makes procedure harder to write / read / maintain and making it more error prone.

Use direct SQL in the procedure so you also avoid problems whrn concatenating NULL values.